# Weak convergence of measures plus convergence of p-th moment

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, weak-convergence

I know there are a bunch of similar questions on here; however, I could not find precisely the formulation I am interested in:

Let $\mu_n \to \mu$ weakly as probability measures on $R^d$ AND additionally assume $\int |x|^p d\mu_n$ is convergent in $\mathbb{R}$ (as a sequence in $n$) for some $p \geq 1$. Does it imply:   lim$\int |x|^p d\mu_n = \int |x|^pd\mu$?.

I know the statement is wrong, if we merely know boundedness of $\int |x|^p d\mu_n$ (hence, the existence of a convergent subsequence) [in this case you need, for example, boundedness with some exponent 1+$\epsilon$], but I'm wondering whether the a priori given convergence of the entire sequence improves the situation significantly.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On $(0,1)$ with Lebesgue measure $m$ let $f_n=nI_{(0,\frac  1 n)}$ and $f=0$. If $\mu_n =m \circ f_n^{-1}$ and  $\mu =m\circ f^{-1}$ then $\mu_n \to \mu$ weakly, $\int |x| d\mu_n(x) =1$ for all $n$ but  $\int |x| d\mu_n(x) \to 1 \neq 0=\int |x|d\mu(x)$.